# ¿Python Programa para separar simbolos terminales y no terminales?

Tags: python

Ya hace pocos días dejé otra pregunta al respecto, en ese entonces no tenía nada de código, pero ahora ya tengo algo realizado y necesito ayuda. 
La idea es la siguiente:
Tengo esto en un txt:

```
program > begin statementlist end
statementlist > statement statementtail
statementtail > statement statementtail
statementtail > 
statement > ip dosp igual expresion pcoma
statement > read pari exprlist pard pcoma
statement > write pari exprlist pard pcoma
idlist > id idtail
idtail > coma id idtail
idtail > 
exprlist > expresion exprtail
exprtail > coma expresion exprtail
exprtail > 
expresion > primary primarytail
primarytail > addop primary primarytail
primarytail > 
primary > pari expresion pard
primary > id
primary > intliteral
addop > mas
addop > menos
systemgoal > program
```

La actividad es "sencilla".
Tengo que realizar un programa que separe los simbolos terminales de los no terminales, basicamente separar el lado izquierdo del derecho.
PERO SIN USAR SPLIT().
Mi idea fue tomar todo el txt en forma de string, darle un list() y tener todas las letras en una lista, luego ir recorriendo la lista con una variable var tomando letra por letra y añadirlas a una lista (Llamemosla lnoterm), al encontrar el simbolo '>' dejar de añadir a lnoterm y comenzar a añadir a otra lista llamada lterm, e igual, ir añadiendo valores a esa lista hasta encontrar un '\n', y seguir añadiendo a la lista lnoterm.
Pretendía hacer eso en el siguiente código, pero no me funciona. 
Cualquier observación es bienvenida, la verdad estoy retomando la programación y me ha costado realizar el ejercicio. Siento que tengo errores lógicos muy simples y me frustra que no me salga.
Ayuda! D:

```
with open("D:/Tecnologico/Materias Actuales/Lenguajes y Automatas/Gramatica/gramatica.txt",'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
print(list(data))
separate=list(data)
lnoterm=[]
lterm=[]
x=0
y=0
var=0


def noterm(var):
    global x    
    car=separate[var]
    if car!='>':
        lnoterm.insert(x,separate[var])
        x=x+1
        var=var+1        
        return noterm(var)
    else:
        term(var)

def term(var):
    global y
    car=separate[var]
    if car!='\n':
        lterm.insert(y,separate[var])
        y=y+1
        var=var+1
        return term(var)
    else:
        noterm(var)

def main():    
    car=separate[var]    
    if var!=len(separate):
        noterm(var)
    else:        
        print('No terminales: ',' ',join(lnoterm))

        print('Terminales: ',' ',join(lterm))


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Entiendo que simbolos terminales son los que aparecen en el lado derecho _pero nunca en el izquierdo_, El problema no es tan "sencillo", especialmente si no te permiten usar `split()`. Yo comenzaría por separar en una lista todas las palabras que aparecen antes del `>` y en otra todas las que aparecen después del `>`. Para esto puede hacerse de forma similar a como tu intentas, pero es algo más complejo pues necesitas "recordar" en alguna variable si ya has visto o no el `>`. Después convertiría esas listas en conjuntos y haría su resta.

Comment: Por otro lado, aunque has intentado usar funciones, tienes el código muy poco estructurado, pues hay muchas variables globales (cosa que debe evitarse en lo posible) y código inicial que mejor estaba en `main()` (lectura del fichero). Por otro lado para añadir caracteres al final de una lista deberías usar `append()` en lugar de `insert()`. Eso te evita también tener que usar las variables `x` e `y`.

Comment: De todas formas yo intentaría otro enfoque más sencillo.Usando `myfile.readlines()` obtienes una lista en la que cada elemento es una línea. Esto te evita tener que andar detectando el `\n`. Puedes hacer una función `procesa_linea()` que recibe una línea, busca el `>` (puedes usar `str.find()`) y usa su posición para dividir en dos (operador _slice_). El lado izquierdo es una palabra, el lado derecho se lo pasa a otra función que busque espacios y te devuelva la lísta de palabras. `procesa_linea()` retorna la palabra hallada antes del `>` y la lista de palabras halladas despues.

Comment: El programa principal iría llamando a `procesa_linea()` para cada línea y recogiendo lo que ésta le devuelve, para ir guardándolo en dos conjuntos: `terminales` y `no_terminales`. Al final se haría `terminales = terminales-no_terminales`.

Comment: Ya que entiendo que esto es un ejercicio de clase, me limito a darte las ideas para que lo intentes tú mismo en lugar de darte el código, pero lo he implementado y funciona.

Comment: Es muy buena idea la que propones. Me ha servido mucho y me gusta que me respondan así: Sin darme la respuesta. Ahora si he visto varios errores en mi código que no notaba. Voy a intentar corregirlo e implementar lo que me propones. Gracias!